# Heap Curroption error in findContours

Tags: opencv, heap-memory, contour, heap-corruption

I have a heap corruption error because of the cv::findContours function. I need help figuring out the solution for this problem.

```
int GetEndPoints(cv::Mat image) 
{
    cv::Mat imgBW = cv::Mat::zeros(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);
    cv::cvtColor(image, imgBW, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    std::cout << std::endl << imgBW.channels();
    cv::threshold(imgBW, imgBW, 150, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::namedWindow("image", 0);
    cv::imshow("image", imgBW);
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    cv::Mat image1 = image.clone();


    // Find the Contours
    std::cout << std::endl << imgBW.channels();
    cv::findContours(imgBW, contours, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    cv::drawContours(image1, contours, -1, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, 8);
    cv::namedWindow("contours", 0);
    cv::imshow("contours", image1);
    cv::waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your program with g++ 4.7.2 and opencv 2.3.1.  I didn't get any messages about heap corruption.  I also ran it through valgrind and got no errors.

Comment: I am using opencv 2.4.5 with visual studio 2010. As i dig in, I feel the problem is during deleting the contours vector.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, and came to the same conclusion: the error is caused by the vector that I passed in going out of scope. Using Visual Studio 2015 and OpenCV 2.4. Maybe it's specific to the Windows builds? And did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You shoud check number of contours you found. I think you get error when there is no contours in contours variable.